# Programatically adding popups into OpenLayers map

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I'm developing a web service and want to inset multiple popups dynamically to a web page according to the request.

What I did was this

```
<script> //injected programmatically
var popups=[];
popups.push('11.1117177 46.077171   Title One   Description one,Second line.    24,24   0,-24');
....
</script>
....


function showPopups() {
    var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
    "Popup layer", {
    style : reconstructedTrajectoryStyle
    });

    var parser = new OpenLayers.Format.Text();
    var src = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326');
    var dest = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913');

    var s, wktLine, features, reprojectedFeatures;
    for (s = 0; s < popups.length; s++) {
    wktLine = popups[s];
    var wktLine1="lat   lon title   description icon    iconSize    iconOffset \n"+wktLine;
    features = parser.read(wktLine1);
    reprojectedFeatures = features.geometry.transform(src, dest);
    vectorLayer.addFeatures(new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
    reprojectedFeatures));
    }

    osmmap.addLayer(vectorLayer);
    osmmap.zoomToExtent(vectorLayer.getDataExtent());
}

$(document).ready(function() {
initialize();
....
showPopups();

});
```

What I got at the end was not successful. I got the error on the browser console saying Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'transform' of undefined ز

What am I doing wrong? Should I use another easier technique?

Answer (score 1):

how many features do you have in your features variable? if you have more, you cant transform it to new projection.

beside this loop [i] in your features array `features[0].geometry.transform(src, dest)`

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 0):

I load a dynamic kml, with all popup ... dynamic kml is a php file that create a kml structure and where i put all information tha i need.

KML is a file that I can define a style and pop-up message, with html format.

I can simply add a various kml file to my OpenLayers map with this simple code:

```
            var sundials = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML esempio con PopUp", { 
            projection: map.displayProjection,
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "../example.kml",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({extractStyles: true,extractAttributes: true})
            })
        });
```

Than, I add function for enable popup on one of my kml file ... search on web select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(sundials) or remind me.

For example.kml file I can create this with php code, that create a file exactly with a normal kml file.

Sample code //php START

echo the header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

echo the style

```
<Style id="sh_ylw-pushpin">
    <IconStyle>
        <scale>1.3</scale>
        <Icon>
            <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
        </Icon>
        <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
    </IconStyle>
    <LineStyle>
        <color>ff0055aa</color>
    </LineStyle>
    <PolyStyle>
        <color>7f00aaff</color>
    </PolyStyle>
</Style>
```

echo the geometry

```
$query = @pg_query( SQL STRING ); while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$the_geom_kml =$row['the_geom_kml'];
$A =$row[$colA];
$B =$row[$colB];
$C =$row[$colC];
$D =$row[$colD];    

echo"
<Placemark>
        <name>$A</name>
        <description>
            <![CDATA[
                superficie: $Be mq
                <br>$C
                <br>$D
            ]]>
        </description>
        <styleUrl>#all_red_1</styleUrl>
        $the_geom_kml</Placemark>
";}
```

the geometry $the_geom_kml is generate from PostGIS function like this

```
ST_AsKML(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_union(the_geom), 3003), 900914)) as the_geom_kml
```

echo the footer

```
</Document></kml>
```

//php END

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Answer to include more details about why you think this answers the Question?  Generally, "about a paragraph" is considered to be the minimum length for Answers (and Questions) here.